# Ceasar Cipher produces wrong result for symbols and spaces

Tags: python, encryption

My character set includes all lower, capital, punctuation, and " ".

Problem exists as such:

`Hello world!` encrypts as `Lipps$Asvph%`  with a shift of 4
The desired answer is `Lipps${svph%`.
and
`Jhss'tl'Pzothls5` decrypts as `Call me IshmaelY`
The desired answer is of course `Call me Ishmael`.

For my table i am using:

```
character_set = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + " " + string.punctuation

which produces: 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

I'm thinking my problem is my character set is listed with more punctuation than the answers set? The problem occurs only with punctuation and spaces it seems.

```
import string

def cipher_cipher_using_lookup(text,  key, characters = string.ascii_lowercase, decrypt=False):

    if key < 0:
        print('key cannot be negative')
        return None

    n = len(characters)
    if decrypt==True:
        key = n - key

    table = str.maketrans(characters, characters[key:]+characters[:key])
    translated_text = text.translate(table)
    
    return translated_text

character_set = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + " " + string.punctuation
#
print(character_set)
plain_text = input('Enter your text: ')
distance = int(input('Enter distance: '))

encrypted = cipher_cipher_using_lookup(plain_text, distance, character_set, decrypt=False)
decrypted = cipher_cipher_using_lookup(plain_text, distance, character_set, decrypt=True)


print('Encrypt text:\n', encrypted)
print('Decrypt text:\n', decrypted)
```

Comment: Why is the desired answer `Lipps${svph%`? A lowercase `w` should be translated to the character 4 locations to its right, or `A`. I don't see any combination of  `string.ascii_lowercase , string.ascii_uppercase,  string.digits , " ",` and `string.punctuation` that would give you a `{` 4 locations after the `w`

Comment: Boss it looks like whole classroom is facing issue in Caesar cipher code ( yesterday I watched the same question multiple times  )... For you boss https://medium.com/@lazyendian_bit/caesar-cipher-python-implementation-982593f1ab45

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are decrypting the original text instead of the encrypted result from the previous call.

Change the decrypt line to use `encrypted` instead of `plain_text`:

```
decrypted = cipher_cipher_using_lookup(encrypted, distance, character_set, decrypt=True)
```

As for the expected encrypted values, they seem to be based on the full 7-bit character set (or at least from space to 126). This gives a different ordering from the one you are using:

```
character_set = "".join(chr(i) for i in range(ord(" "),127))
```

*Note that you could support negative keys and simplify the code a bit by swapping the target characters with the originals instead of inverting the key value to decrypt:*

```
mapping = characters[key:]+characters[:key]
if decrypt:
    characters,mapping = mapping,characters
table = str.maketrans(characters,mapping)
return text.translate(table)
```

Also, if the full character set is the only character list to work from, you could simplify the function to a single line (and use the negative of the key to decrypt):

```
def cipher_cipher_using_lookup(text, key):
    return text.translate({c+32:(c+95+key)%95+32 for c in range(95)})

cipher_cipher_using_lookup("Hello world!",4)   # Lipps${svph%
cipher_cipher_using_lookup("Lipps${svph%",-4)  # Hello world!
```